# Oracle - Return all clients which TODAY is the day that they made more orders

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this cenario:
I need to return a list of clients that i need to contact today, if this is the day that they most commonly make their orders.
example:

```
SELECT 
     p.IDCOMPANY  AS IDCOMPANY   ,
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM p.DATEORDER)  AS DAY,
    COUNT(EXTRACT(DAY FROM p.DATEORDER))  AS QUANTITY
    FROM ORDERS p 
    GROUP BY p.IDCOMPANY ,EXTRACT(DAY FROM p.DATEORDER)
    ORDER BY p.IDCOMPANY,QUANTITY DESC, DAY
```

i have only been able to return the groups ordered by the day they most did orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The day that occurs most often for a company in the table is called the statistical mode. Oracle's function for that is `STATS_MODE`.

```
select idcompany
from orders
group by idcompany
having stats_mode(extract(day from dateorder)) = extract(day from sysdate);
```

The problem with that: There can be ties, and in that case the DBMS will pick one day arbitrarily. So while today (Thursday) may be the company's top day, we may not see it, if Monday is also a top day with the exact same amount of orders.

We need a better query hence. Here is a query that deals with ties properly:

```
select idcompany, order_day, cnt
from
(
  select
    idcompany,
    extract(day from dateorder) as order_day,
    count(*) as cnt,
    max(count(*)) over (partition by idcompany) as max_cnt
  from orders
  group by idcompany, extract(day from dateorder)
)
where cnt = max_cnt and order_day = extract(day from sysdate);
```